# How do I modify the length and with of a Drupal Mega Slider?

Tags: drupal-7

The Drupal CMS has many themes available to customized this open source php software.  I am using Drupal 7.x.  I am using the popular theme is porto.
[image]

Porto comes with a Mega Slider component.  And that is what I am using here.  I am using the Mega Slider that comes with Porto.

[image]

I have going through the tutorial to created a test slider and it looks fine.  But the width spans the length of the front page.  In the configuration settings of the control, I have disabled the checkbox to allow for this width but this has had no effect or change in the display.

I have assigned the dimensions of the control to 644 X 320 and I have even made sure that each photo used as the main image of each pannel is this width.  But this does not change anything.

Please advise or ask for more clarification.